# Android - Sending audio-file with MMS

Tags: android, audio, android-intent, mms

Im using the following code to send audio-files through email, dropbox +++..
This is not giving me the option to send the same file through MMS..
Anyone know how to attach it to a MMS and let the user send if he/she wants?

```
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("audio/3gpp");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + aFile));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Send file"));
```

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 0):

you can used this code..

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
            sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
            sendIntent.putExtra("address", "9999999999");
            sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "if you are sending text");   
            final File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),"Downloadtest.3gp");
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file1);

            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            sendIntent.setType("video/3gp");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send file"));
```

you have to used your appropriate set type .if audio then **audio/***,image then **image/png**

This code work my samsung nexus,ace 5830 but not working htc amaze.If any one found any solution then please give snippet.